Writing a byte=x00 in a file with bash
I'd like to write the unprintable ASCII characters x00 into a file with bash.
If I type:
printf $'\x00'$'\x01'$'\x02'$'\x03'$'\x04'$'\x05' > file-1.txt

and check with hexedit:
hexedit file-1.txt
00000000   01 02 03 04  05

the file begins with x01 instead of x00.
Similarly, writing 50 x00 byte in a file produces an empty file:
printf '' > file-2.txt

for ((i=50 ; i>0 ; i--)); do
    printf $'\x00' >> file-2.txt
done

ll file-2.txt

-rw------- 1 user1 user1 0 nov.   3 14:02 file-2.txt

Any solution?

Bash strings can't contain NUL characters so $'\x00' expands to an empty string.  This should do what you want: printf '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05' > file-1.txt
